# Как быстро создать нейросеть которая меняет голос

Tags: нейронные-сети, tensorflow

Задача такова: 
нужно создать нейросеть, которую можно обучить аудиофайлами с голосом (например Шаляпина),
 чтобы после этого на вход ей давать любой голос,
 а на выходе получать голос Шаляпина.

Какие удобные способы решения этой задачи уже существуют ?
Какой фреймворк проще (предпочтительнее) использовать ?
В общем хочу быстрее приступить к реализации. 
Думаю эта задача уже решена и решение помещено в какую-то библиотеку.

Answer (score 2):

"Как **быстро** создать нейросеть которая меняет голос" - залезть в Гуугл, сформулировать запрос, пройти по полученным ссылкам, отобрать ту технологию, которая вам наиболее подходит (ибо их масса), изучит как с ней работать, встроить в свой проект, получить профит.

Поскольку короновирус как-то так повлиял на людей, что большинство разучилось пользоваться Гууглом, сделаю первый шаг за вас.

https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning

https://veravoice.ai/

https://tproger.ru/news/lyrebird-voice-api/

https://www.descript.com/lyrebird-ai?source=lyrebird

https://www.resemble.ai/

https://proglib.io/p/golosovoy-deepfake-ili-kak-rabotaet-tehnologiya-klonirovaniya-golosa-2019-12-11

https://www.descript.com/

https://habr.com/ru/post/403413/

https://vc.ru/services/80761-specialisty-sozdali-neyroset-dlya-sozdaniya-poddelnyh-golosov

Быстрее - вряд ли получиться.

Comment: Я думаю найти специалиста который уже реализовывал эту задачу или знаком с её реализацией и подскажет конкретную библиотеку которая на это способна или может даже существующую нейросеть для решения этой задачи

Comment: Тоже правильное решение.

Answer (score 0):

Самое лучшее из доступного и публично описанного:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6oQ0Obi14rM

Специалиста, который это уже реализовывал, проще всего нанять лет через 20.

Comment: Это уже что то из того что мне надо, но это видео не слишком информативно